# JSON parse inside jquery

Tags: jquery, json

collegue of mine is with one function returning to me for example this string

```
"a:11:{s:7:\"exports\";s:43:\"%3Bbazos%3Brealityexport%3Breality%3Bnehnut\";s:10:\"bazos_date\";s:10:\"0000-00-00\";s:10:\"bazos_idad\";s:8:\"34432067\";s:12:\"bazos_status\";s:2:\"OK\";s:9:\"rexp_date\";s:10:\"2013-11-13\";s:9:\"real_date\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"real_idad\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"real_status\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"nehnut_date\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"nehnut_idad\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"nehnut_status\";s:0:\"\";}"
```

I need to make json from it, or somehow acces the data, i tried $.parseJSON but it tell's me it's not json object...can someone help me?

Comment: It's not valid JSON - so you can't parse it as JSON, validate through www.jsonlint.com

Comment: Where is the string from? It seems that the number (like s:10) is the number of characters in the string.

Comment: It looks like your colleague is doing a serialize($object) in PHP. Try json_encode($object).

Comment: Json works like this {key:value, key:value, ...}, your "json" is like this {type:size:value; type:size:value; ...} which is obviously not json

Comment: yeah, but there's problem it's stored in db this way and another part of company is working on that...but i found out it's serialized php object, so unserialize did the magic... :) thanks for help anywy :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it's not valid JSON so parseJSON will never work. JSON will always be in the form`{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}` and so on. Your snippet seems to have semi-colons instead of commas and some form of double key (`a:11:{...`) as well as missing double quotes
You must either get the function to return valid JSON or use an alternate means like regex to parse the string into something useful. I'd recommend the first option.